# how to see NeuG/Fraucheky True Random Number Generator?

Tags: linux, usb

I recently purchased an FST-01 from the Free Software Foundation with
NeuG and Fraucheky pre-installed: http://shop.fsf.org/product/usb/

I am running Debian Jessie and even when I plugged it in, the
/dev/ttyACM0 device did not appear :-( Although it does appear in
`lsusb`

Bus 001 Device 008: ID 234b:0004

and I see the following in `dmesg`

```
  usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
  usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=234b, idProduct=0004
  usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
  usb 1-1: Product: Fraucheky
  usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Free Software Initiative of Japan
  usb 1-1: SerialNumber: FSIJ-0.0
  usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
  scsi8 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
  scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     FSIJ     Fraucheky        1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
  sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
  sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 128 512-byte logical blocks: (65.5 kB/64.0 KiB)
  sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
  sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
  sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
  sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
   sdc:
  sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I followed the only available instructions that I could find, at http://www.gniibe.org/FST-01/q_and_a/neug-standalone-device.html but I have the following to report on that:

1. I removed `modemmanager` and rebooted.
2. I cannot run `stty` because there is no device.
3. I cannot run `dd` because there is no device.
4. I tried "Systemd 2014-01-12" but it did not create a device.
5. I tried "Start on boot 2012-11-07" but it did not create a device.
6. I tried "Plug-and-play 2012-11-08" but it did not create a device.

I also noticed that the instructions have device number 0001 whereas
`lsusb` tells me that I have device 0004, so I tried the relevant steps again using
device number 0004 but it also didn't do anything.

The device seems to be completely invisible to my computer and I don't really know what to do with the `/dev/sdc` that it's created.

How can I use this wonderful device?

**UPDATE** mounting `/dev/sdc` as a filesystem, all I can see is the documentation that I already found at http://www.gniibe.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using command-line interface.  In Debian, there is a package named 'eject'.  Please install the package and then, you can do:
`# eject /dev/sdc` to stop the Fraucheky disk.

Then, NeuG will run.

Comment: FYI on FreeBSD: you need to add a usbconfig quirk `UQ_MSC_FORCE_PROTO_UFI`. See https://gist.github.com/jj1bdx/0d9eb3d2b2783c0c60f6 for the further details.

Comment: Do you have to do this on every boot?